# Compare whether incident is new or already exists

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

There is an algorithm that identifies issues/incidents in a network. After that it writes all the cases into a DB. Lets say it looks like (simplified):

| ID | Date | Case |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| B1 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |
| C1 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |
| A1 | 2022-01-02 | NA |
| C1 | 2022-01-02 | NA |
| A1 | 2022-01-03 | NA |
| B1 | 2022-01-03 | NA |
| C1 | 2022-01-03 | NA |

Each row represents an incident. 
Now I want to identify if an incident already existed the last time we ran this script. For this it should check the actual Date and compare it with the last existing date in the table.
*Note: it can occur that the last day was not yesterday, it might be that there is a difference up to 7 days*.

So the logical is:

- compare the second highest `date` value in this `ID` group with the second highest `Date` from full `df`
- If it's the same it means, case already exists. Then take it's last `Case` number. If it's new, create a new `Case` number (`max(Case) + 1`)

***Update 11.05.2022 - 17:02:***

- It should consider existing `Case` values and not overwrite them. Or with other words, it should overwrite/fill the `NA`s. There will never be `NA`s in between. The existing cases always have a number, the new ones doesn't. 100%.

Expected result:

| ID | Date | Case | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |  |
| B1 | 2022-01-01 | 2 |  |
| C1 | 2022-01-01 | 3 |  |
| A1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |  |
| C1 | 2022-01-02 | 3 |  |
| A1 | 2022-01-03 | 1 |  |
| B1 | 2022-01-03 | 4 | New case, as there wasn't B1 on 2022-01-02 |
| C1 | 2022-01-03 | 3 |  |

I was able to identify the second highest Dates:

```
> df[, nth(unique(Date),length(unique(Date))-1), ID]
   ID         V1
1: A1 2022-01-02 ## TRUE, as it's the second highest Date
2: B1 2022-01-01 ## FALSE, as it's not the second highest Date
3: C1 2022-01-02 ## TRUE, as it's the second highest Date
> df[, nth(unique(Date),length(unique(Date))-1)]
[1] "2022-01-02" ## Second highest Date in df
```

But now I'm struggling with creating a new column with this condition. Can somebody please help? `data.table` solution prefered, but `dplyr` is great as well.

---

**MWE**

```
library(data.table)

df = data.table(ID=c("A1", "B1", "C1", "A1", "C1", "A1", "B1", "C1"),
            Date=as.Date(c("2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-02","2022-01-03", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-03")),
            Case = NA)


Goal = data.table(ID=c("A1", "B1", "C1", "A1", "C1", "A1", "B1", "C1"),
                Date=as.Date(c("2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-01","2022-01-02","2022-01-02","2022-01-03", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-03")),
                Case=c(1,2,3,1,3,1,4,3))
```

Comment: There is no `Case` column in the example you shared. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks. I've updated it. Now the `Case` column is empty, so each incident is initially a new case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
df[order(Date), d:=c(1,diff(Date)), by = ID][
  order(d,ID),case:=rleid(ID,d)][
    ,d:=NULL]
```

Output:

```
   ID       Date case
1: A1 2022-01-01    1
2: B1 2022-01-01    2
3: C1 2022-01-01    3
4: A1 2022-01-02    1
5: C1 2022-01-02    3
6: A1 2022-01-03    1
7: B1 2022-01-03    4
8: C1 2022-01-03    3
```

If you actually want the comment column, you can refine the above, like this:

```
df[order(Date), d:=c(1,diff(Date)), by = ID][
  order(d,ID),`:=`(
    case=rleid(ID,d),
    comment=fifelse(d!=1,paste0("New case, as there was no ", ID, " on ",Date-1),""))][
      ,d:=NULL][]
```

Output:

```
   ID       Date case                                    comment
1: A1 2022-01-01    1                                           
2: B1 2022-01-01    2                                           
3: C1 2022-01-01    3                                           
4: A1 2022-01-02    1                                           
5: C1 2022-01-02    3                                           
6: A1 2022-01-03    1                                           
7: B1 2022-01-03    4 New case, as there was no B1 on 2022-01-02
8: C1 2022-01-03    3
```

Comment: That look great *upvote*. I'll check it with my real code. If it works I'll accept this answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Great, let me know if I missed something. I wasn't sure about your comment re 7th day, etc.... Also, what is the same incident occurs multiple times on the same day?  Might need to adjust for that possibility.. One simple adjustment would be to start the pipeline with `unique(df[,.(ID,date)])`, and then join back if you need all the rows.

Comment: If it occurs multiple times a day I'll remove the first ones anyway. So I think your solution is perfect.

Comment: One question. How could I run this function if some Cases are filled with numbers, others are NA? If I filter NA out it starts from 0, if I don't filter NA it overwrites the existing cases. Sorry, this maybe was not good enough specified.

Comment: hm, I didn't use your Case column at all (i.e. i don't think it was even there when you originally posted). If the Case column already has some values, should these be overwritten?  Perhaps an example will help... If initial values should be retained, what happens if an NA occurs BEFORE an existing value for a particular ID (or would that never happen?)

Comment: No, if a `Case` value is set, it shouldn't be overwritten. (I've updated the question... sorry again). It should consider the Case column and overwrite the `NA`s. Workflow is: I query all the cases and append the new ones. The existing ones are having these values, the new ones doesn't.

Comment: There will never be a NA in between. The old ones always have Case numbers, the new ones doesn't. This is 100% sure.

Comment: I found a solution with a bit tweeking. As the initial post was different, I'll accept your answer. And my solution: I load `ID, Case` where `Date` is `max(Date)` from SQL DB. Then join it with my dataframe by `ID`. Where I have a `Case` I'll take it. For all the others, I create a `seq(max(Case) + 1, max(Case) + 1 + length(df$ID), 1)` and fill these values into the NA column.

Comment: great! sounds like success!